# Kubuntu asking for root access to update proxy

Tags: linux, security

I have Kubuntu 18.10 installed on my PC with the latest KDE/Plasma backports. A dialog popped up last night right after login, requesting administrator privileges to set the system proxy for software downloads (screenshot below). I'm on my home network, don't have a proxy and have never tried to configure one.

[image: Screenshot: Proxy superuser request]

Should I be worried? My first instinct was to yank the power cable and block the computer from the network at the router, as I'm concerned it could be the result of malware. I haven't found any evidence of that though, and googling the issue just turns up Red Hat package bug reports from 2011.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? At the moment I'm inclined to put the PC back on the network, see if it happens again, and if so try to track down that PID and where the packagekit/polkit request is coming from.

Comment: Thanks G-Man, appreciated. Noob here, did wonder why it wasn't displaying inline.

Comment: I don't think that's malware.  It was probably setup automatically originally, and now it requires updating.  See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/gtk-doc/PackageKit.html and https://github.com/hughsie/PackageKit/blob/master/docs/setting-the-proxy.txt.  The purpose may be to handle corporate networks, but they may just set it up by default, regardless.

Comment: Thing is, the default would be no proxy. I can't think of any legitimate reason to request changing that, unprompted. I'm not on a corporate network and don't have a proxy - so who/what is requesting to add a man-in-the-middle between the PC and the official download repositories?  I have another near identical machine built using the same script with the same packages and patches. The dialog hasn't popped up there, I might be reassured that this is a package bug if it had (although I suppose it might just mean I had TWO compromised PCs).